# Can you show that ($3^n - 1$) is always divisible by 4?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If n is even, show that ($3^n - 1$)/2 is always divisible by 4, so it can never be prime.

How can i show that ($3^n - 1$)/2  is divisible by 4? I tried dividing the expression by 4 and seeing if the terms cancelled in any predictable way but I still cannot prove it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  `$3^n$` shows up as $3^n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even , $3^n-1$ has the form $9^m-1$ hence is divisible by $8$

Comment: You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use induction !

The base case is clear. Suppose that, for some $n$, the term $\frac{3^{2n}-1}{2}$ is divisible by 4.

Then show that $\frac{3^{2n+2}-1}{2}= 9\frac{3^{2n}-1}{2}+4$ .

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

$$3^{2m}-1=9^m-1 \equiv 1^m -1\equiv 0 \pmod{8}$$

Hence $3^{2m}-1$ is divisible  by $8$ and hence $\frac{3^{2m}-1}{2}$ is divisible by $4$.

Clearly this is not true when $n$ is odd.